# Why have an abstract class and abstract variables/methods in an Interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, abstract-class

I was given an Interface from another team to include in my code for database logging. The Interface is filled with only abstract classes and variables/methods. What is the reason to do this?

It does not have any logic. I am simply overriding trace and isTraceEnabled when I extend Logger.

I can`t get my head around it. What is the point of having methods implemented that do nothing but return a specific value they expect?

```
public abstract class Logger {
    public abstract void trace(String message);
    public abstract bool isTraceEnabled { get; }
}
```

Comment: I would ask them to provide one of their concrete classes as an example for how it's expected to be used.

Answer (score 4):

When *they* give you an interface like that, it means one of two things:

- If *they* are requesting logging from your library, while your library is responsible for performing database logging, then you need to define a class that *extends* `Logger`, and provide implementation of each of its abstract methods.
- If *you* are using `Logger` to perform logging which their library provides to you, then they should provide a way for you to get an *instance* of a class extending the abstract `Logger` class. In this case you should not be extending the class at all: you should get an instance of it upfront, store it in a variable of type `Logger`, and program to its interface.

Comment: i believe it to be he first point. I extended logger and have implemented each abstract method. My methods do not do anything because I do not know what they should be doing. The trace method could print anything I want which does not seem right. Perhaps they expect me to just know what the output should be?...

Comment: @DavidLeverett If they expect you to do DB logging, then your implementation should be doing DB logging, not printing anything.

Comment: I would speculate that they are expecting you to control the tracing and storing the logging. I'd guess they are requiring you to provide an instance of that Logger child class somewhere?  They are likely checking the isTraceEnabled property for true, and if it is, they are calling the trace() method with information you should be logging somewhere.

Comment: All else fails, ask the team that provided you with the Logger what they recommend, or if they have any examples of what other teams who've used the Logger typically do.